# Как составить запрос к БД mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть структура базы:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сначала выбираю всех юзеров и группы за которыми они следят из таблицы User. Далее необходимо получить количество людей к каждой группе, эти данные надо подтянуть из таблицы Groups (связь по полю group) теперь ещё неплохо бы подтянуть баланс юзера каждого из balance здесь id это uid в User.

Работает запрос:

```
SELECT
t1.uid,
t1.group,
t2.people
FROM User AS t1, Groups AS t2
WHERE t1.group = t2.group
```

Но в таблице Groups несколько записей и надо выбрать где people максимальное значение. Поменяем в запросе **t2.people** на **t2.MAX(people)** и всё перестаёт работать. Или хотя бы как мне LIMIT поставить что бы из Groups только 1 запись выбиралась?

Comment: Проверьте запятые.

Comment: @D-side да спасибо, там была ошибка

Comment: Если будет время - оформите, пожалуйста, ответом, чтобы пришедшие из поисковых систем пользователи могли увидеть его и сопоставить с их ситуацией

Answer (score 1, accepted):

t2.MAX(people) замените на MAX(t2.people)